# can i use variable in load data infile in mysql

Tags: mysql

I've only got a 'working knowledge' of mysql.

Is it possible to use a variable in the `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement below. I'm getting a syntax error for the `concat`.

```
SET @DATA_DIR='/Documents/Projects/OCSCommerce/admin/src/main/testdata/csv';

-- import the roles
SELECT 'Importing roles' AS ' ';
LOAD DATA INFILE concat(@DATA_DIR, 'roles.csv') replace
INTO TABLE roles
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(id, created, lastUpdated, code, name, createUser_id, lastUpdateUser_id, visible, markForDelete);
```

Also if I could get the directory value from an environment variable, that's even better!

Comment: No, the filename has to be a literal. If you need to create this dynamically, you'll have to use a stored procedure that uses `PREPARE`.

Comment: ah okay thanks, that's a worry. Maybe shell scripting might be solution...

Comment: Yes, creating the `LOAD DATA` command in some other language is another solution.